# Adding reactive.rb to project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react.rb

I have a trouble with adding react.rb to my project.

**At first,** [after all steps](https://github.com/reactrb/todo-tutorial) with adding `reactive_rails_generator` is done, and i started my app, i have got the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `load_asset' for Opal::Sprockets:Module):

<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

app/views/layouts/grid/layout.html.erb:15:

I see all need gem's In Gemfile  to work with react.rb

```
gem 'reactive-ruby' gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.3.0' gem 'opal-rails' gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby gem 'react-router-rails', '~>0.13.3' gem 'reactive-router' gem 'reactive-record'
```

Can anyone help with that?

**At second,** i have a rake task message:

```
Warning:[rake --tasks] DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
```

Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from  at /Users/serzh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/opal-0.8.0/lib/opal/sprockets/processor.rb:165)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from  at /Users/serzh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/opal-0.8.0/lib/opal/sprockets/processor.rb:166)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
(called from  at /Users/serzh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/opal-0.8.0/lib/opal/sprockets/erb.rb:23)

Comment: I am recently playing with react and rails. I used `gem 'react-rails'` gem. But why did you include all those others gems?

Comment: Look [this tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers) to see how the author did the set up.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Well, because i'm trying to use [react.rb](http://reactrb.org), not only react-rails gem.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. It is something I need to check.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, and all here.
I have added the issue with this little bug in `reactive-rails-generator` [here](https://github.com/loicboutet/reactive-rails-generator/issues/8).

So, after adding to Gemfile `gem 'sprockets'`, everything works good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a deprecated version.  The repo has moved, and the up to date version is here: [reactrb-rails-generator](https://github.com/reactrb/reactrb-rails-generator)

We thought github was automatically forwarding... Apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

check this this blog post - it may help
https://medium.com/@yoniweisbrod/how-we-integrate-react-with-rails-at-ivy-b90f27751a00#.p2vlihlcx

Comment: Guy - nice blog post but the question is about reactrb which your post does not address (but you should look into reactrb :-)